What is the connection of Dattatreya with Maha Kumbh?
I heard that Dattatreya travels from one Kumbh to another Kumbh. Is this true? I also heard that Matsya Purana has a reference to Kumbh. But could not find the specific verse. Where can I find the reference and the detailed narration?
